# Problem with the output implemented " Iterative FFT DIT Radix2 " algorithm matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, simulink, spectrum, radix-sort

I´m trying to implement my own FFT with the **iterative Radix2 algorithm** (I even thought about using the recursive one but it seems Simulink doesn´t allow me to).
I tried all of the possible variations of it, like DIT and DIF, but I always get the same problem: the output doesn´t make much sense to me.
They have similar output thou, both DIF and DIT, both kinds implemented with different variations of the code.

Needing this algorithm for a real application, the signal will be buffered and those data packages are then windowed and overlapped. The window function will be then averaged and sent to the next block in Simulink in order to get a **Welch Spectral estimation**.

Here is my code for (one of) the DIT version I implemented:

```
function [FFT,Wk,k] = radix2(u,k_old,lap) %lap = 512 = 1024/2 with 1024 Window size

N = length(u);
P = log2(N);
FFT = zeros(N,1)+0*1j;
omega = 0j;

% Hann Window
n1 = (k_old)*lap:(N+k_old*lap-1);
w1 = sin(pi.*n1/(N-1)).^2;
z1 = u.*w1';
z1=z1';

% Average
Wk = 0;
for i=1:N
    Wk = Wk + w1(i)^2;
end

%% Algorithm
A = z1(bitrevorder(1:N));
for s=1:log2(N)
    m=2^s;
    Wm = exp(2*pi*1j/m)
    W = 1 +0j;
    for j= 1:m/2
        for k=j:m:(N)
            odd = W*A(k+m/2)
            even = A(k);
            FFT(k)=odd + even;
            FFT(k+m/2) =even-odd;
        end
        W = W*Wm;
    end
end
```

and this is the output

[image: Amplitude-Frequency Plot]

Instead of having two/three distinct spikes (the input is a sinus signal with some noise, even if I switch the noise off or the window function, the result doesn´t change much, so those are correct), I get this butterfly-shaped signal. Why does it look like that?

I first thought it was a frequency normalization Problem but, it didn´t solve it.

I really hope anyone can help and that the question isn´t too stupid, I´m completely lost now.

*Re-edit:*

The reason is that I am making parallelisms between different techniques for dynamic parameter estimation: Lock-In Amplifier, Welch with DFT, FFT, Goertzel, and other methods. Then I am comparing things like variance, timing, FLOPS... so self-implementing it is exactly the focal point of my work. I know that welch already exists in Matlab and Simulink but it brings me nothing for the special purpose of my research. Also, most of my versions are perfectly working, the only one issue is the **iterative FFT** implementation which doesn´t look like a Fourier Transform and I don´t really get the reason why.

The output should show two spikes at + and -50Hz, one at 0Hz because of a proportional term of the signal and some other smaller around, insignificant compared to the +-50Hz and the 0 one.

Comment: Why not use the `fft` function in MATLAB?  Why would you want to reimplement that? People make their own implementation to understand how it works, but not for use in a real application. Use the very efficient, well tested implementation that comes with your software.

Comment: As I said in the comment before I want to study the possible implementations and their structure, count the flops, and so on, so I do need the whole implementation, doesn´t matter if it is worse. It has to fit in a comparison paper with good explanations why is it better or worse than another one. Why is it so important to know why I do need it for, when the question is pure structural? 
You see, even if the Flops for a radix2 implementation is normally counted N*log2(N), also the structure itself can slightly optimize or not the algorithm, I wanna see this.
Thank you anyways.

Comment: If I were reviewing your paper I’d say the same thing. You’re comparing A to B, but B uses a shitty custom FFT implementation, then the comparison is not fair. In the times of multi-threading, SIMD instructions, pipelining, etc, FLOPS have become irrelevant. Use an optimized implementation and compare time, or energy usage, or whatever is relevant.

Comment: Also, I wasn’t asking what you need it for, it was a rhetorical question. I was telling you not to do this. It’s a recommendation that comes from several decades of experience. Don’t reinvent the wheel, and don’t reimplement the FFT.

Answer (score -2):

1.- Welch is already the default Window used in the Spectrum Analyzer block.

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/spbscopes.spectrumanalyzerconfiguration.html#btr7s99-1_sep_mw_2f96bfab-faf1-44c2-952f-d7fe5303d73b

Why do you want to write again what is already implemented?

2.- there's also command pwelch for spectrum estimates

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/welch-spectrum-estimates.html?searchHighlight=welch&s_tid=srchtitle

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html?searchHighlight=welch.m&s_tid=srchtitle

3.- and welch directly

4.- Also read this

[https://uk.mathworks.com/support/search.html/answers/18485-fft-spectrum-or-welch-spectrum.html?fq[]=asset_type_name:answer&fq[]=category:signal/nonparametric-spectral-estimation&page=1](https://uk.mathworks.com/support/search.html/answers/18485-fft-spectrum-or-welch-spectrum.html?fq%5B%5D=asset_type_name:answer&fq%5B%5D=category:signal/nonparametric-spectral-estimation&page=1)

5.- and these 2

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53464-welch-s-cross-power-spectral-density?s_tid=srchtitle

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34383-calculate-psd-of-a-signal-using-welch-algorithm?s_tid=srchtitle